# Counting longest streak

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need help in creating a formula that will calculate the longest streak for the TRUE values.

For example, I have the following value TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE. In this example, the highest number of times that the value TRUE is continuous is 4 times.

I attached a [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SDDABlFggMzp-GYeUk4--ZaxwZFHos8UMChAvr70_oc/edit?usp=sharing). Thank you in advance!

I tried this formula but it didn't work the way that I wanted to.

```js
=ArrayFormula(MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(B4:O4=TRUE,ROW(B4:O4)),IF(B4:O4<>TRUE,ROW(B4:O4)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SCAN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12569094?hl=en)

```cpp
=MAX(SCAN(,B4:O4,LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c,a+1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `reduce` such as the example below.

```js
=array_constrain(reduce({0,0,true},B4:O4,
                        lambda(a,c,
                               let(currentStreak,if(c*index(a,3),index(a,2)+1,1*c),    
                                   longestStreak,if(currentStreak>index(a,1),currentStreak,index(a,1)),
                                   {longestStreak,currentStreak,c}))),
                 1,2)
```

That fills your current streak cell as well.

Although, *a thought*: how are you going to grow your sheet? If a new entry needs to be added, are you going to "insert column"? If so, will `B4:O4` change automatically? It's usually better to grow your sheet in a column (preferred) or row exclusively and use a different column or row entirely to display transformed/aggregated data and thus use infinite ranges.